# Swift Dictionary avoid storing empty dictionaries in values with higher order functions

Tags: ios, swift

I want my top level dictionary "Products" to store only a non empty dictionary of sub products. Is there a way to write the code below with higher order functions like *reduce function* instead using *if !subProductDictionary.isEmpty* ?

```
var productDictionary = [String: Any]()
productDictionary["key 1"] = "value 1"

var subProductDictionary = [String: Any]()

if !subProductDictionary.isEmpty {
    productDictionary["subProductsKey"] = subProductDictionary
}
```

*** edit

I would like to use the fact that when Dictionaries do not store nil values, so to transform *subProductDictionary* to nil

Comment: I would remodel your data entirely to remove any `[String: Any]` dictionaries. It is much better to model your data using Structs that specifically map to your domain model. That way you can also build in the Logic that you are trying to add but inside the model itself.

Comment: You should use a class/struct rather than `[String: Any]` to store your data. Why are you using a `[String: Any]`?

Comment: This question is about coding and not about architecture choices.

Comment: I don't see where `reduce()` would be used here...

Comment: reduce was mentioned to indicate what means for me higher order function

Comment: How deeply nested are your dictionaries?

Comment: In that case there is just a one level

Comment: Dictionaries can store nil values. I wouldn't recommend it, but I wouldn't recommend  what you're doing, either. And neither would anybody else, it seems.

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA I understand what the question was about. But by using a well modelled data structure you would negate the need for a higher order function to do this in the first place. So yes... you asked a question. But from everything I can see in your code it is a question that didn't need asking and is in fact the wrong question to be asking.

Comment: This question is only about capabilities of Swift and higher order functions. This is not a question for 'Code Review' site

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about higher-order functions here but this might be useful:

```
extension Dictionary {
  var nonEmpty: Self? {
    isEmpty ? nil : self
  }
}

var things: [String: Any] = [:]
let dict: [String: Any] = [:]
things["A"] = dict
things["B"] = dict.nonEmpty
```

Comment: Yes, with this one I can write a one liner. +1

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
var productDictionary = [String: Any]()
productDictionary["key 1"] = "value 1"

var subProductDictionary = [String: Any]()

if !subProductDictionary.isEmpty {
    productDictionary["subProductsKey"] = subProductDictionary
}

*** "Optional with flatMap" instead "if"

productDictionary["subProductsKey"] = Optional(subProductDictionary).flatMap { $0.count == 0 ? nil : $0 }
```